# Sort a Query alphabetically?

Tags: sorting

I have this query and I can't figure out how to sort it alphabetically. Can anyone help me?

```
=QUERY({'Cohort 24'!E4:O;'Cohort 25'!E4:O;'Cohort 26'!E4:O;'Cohort 27'!D4:N},"select * where Col1 is not null  or Col2 is not null or Col3 is not null or Col4 is not null or Col5 is not null ")
```

The first column is last names and I want to sort it alphabetically by that column.

I did add order by col1 at the end and got this
Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: col1

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem. You also forgot to give *any* indication what language this is written in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function in Google Sheets.

The second argument to the function is the SQL-ish syntax of the [Google Visualization API Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).

That being the case - look at [this section](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#order-by) of the docs on the Query Language:

I think all you really need to do to order by Col1 is add the `order by Col1` clause at the end!

> #### Order By
>
> The order by clause is used to sort the rows by the values in specified columns.
>
> Items in an order by clause can be column identifiers, or the output of aggregation functions, scalar functions, or operators.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> order by dept, salary desc
> ```

> ```
> select dept, max(salary) group by dept order by max(salary)
> ```